# Could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider' - AzureRedisSessionStateProvider

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-redis-cache, session-state-provider

I am using Redis Azure cache for session, but when deployed in Azure I receive the following error, Could not load type 'Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider'

I had tried many times by uninstalling and re-installing the packages and modifying the webconfig but yet the same issue.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Does it work on local host? Is this being used by a ASP.NET web app? Are your code in C#? You can be more specific.

Comment: Yes the code is in c# and the application is deployed as a web role in Azure. It doesn't works in local host though. The issue seems to be a open issue in RedisSessionStateProvider and hence any solution would be a great help..

Comment: Thanks for the input. Are you able to provide the link on the open issue you mentioned about in RedisSessionStateProvider?

Comment: Thank you for replying back. The link : https://recordnotfound.com/aspnet-redis-providers-Azure-42841

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: The issue seems to be open in a GitHub forum and not sure whether its has any solution elsewhere.. Awaiting for the solution to this..

Comment: Has anyone has any solution for this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers/issues/15 (please provide details here) Please send complete stack trace along with details about what version of VS you are using with which kind of ASP.NET project and what version of .NET you are using. If you can provide reproducible app that would be much helpful to debug and fix issue.